# Is there a solution to read the RAR files of version 5 using Junrar library?

Tags: java, rar

I'm writing part of Java application responsible for reading archive files of different formats and preparing a preview mode.

Junrar library appeared to be the most reliable to work with RAR format, but it doesn't support the latest version 5 of rar. Only earlier versions are supported.

Junrar dev team confirms this fact here:
https://github.com/junrar/junrar/issues/23

Winrar by default creates rar files of version 5, but checkbox 'RAR4' in properties helps to create a file of version 4 - which is perfect to work with. But you have to click it every time you archive the file - that's not a good way (earlier versions of Winrar can't be downloaded from official website).

In my case file is stored as a byte array. I don't need to UNRAR file, i just read it - i need 'name' and 'size' of every file inside of it - thus i prepare preview data of archive content as a small HTML table.

Do you know any other good library to work with Rar format? I can't find any.
Or maybe you can imagine some good workarounds?

Comment: Concerning the "check the box everytime", depending on your use case you could benefit from using the winrar command line. `-ma4` would specify to use the RAR4 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no available solution to unrar RAR5 archives except Winrar itself. You may call it as external program if it is possible on your OS.
I am also treating archives of different formats and I am using junrar for extracting RAR, RAR5 archives remain untreated.
Junrar initially was developed by Edmund Wagner, and some time ago the support was renewed by [Beothorn](https://github.com/beothorn). But, much to my regret, he is not planning to implement RAR5 support for some reason.
I have also checked [Raroscope](https://github.com/radarsh/raroscope), it does not support RAR 5 neither.

By the way, another archive, which is not supported by open source java library, is ARJ.

Comment: So you just leave RAR5 as unsupported format among others?

Comment: Yes, I am importing it to repository as is. But in case it becomes critical I shall use command line utility from Winrar as I am doing with arj.